# Web Scrape - Python - If "text" in string then string = "text" issue - conflicting commands?

Tags: python

I have an unusual one

Do `" "` and `' '` have different meanings in python maybe?

the example is this:

```py
calibre = soup.select_one('h1[itemprop="name"]')
gun_calibre = calibre.text if calibre else ''
if "410 Gauge" in gun_calibre:
    gun_calibre = gun_calibre.replace(gun_calibre,"410 Gauge")
if "10 Gauge" in gun_calibre:
    gun_calibre = gun_calibre.replace(gun_calibre,"10 Gauge")
```

in the above example if I have the string "Mossberg 410 Gauge shotgun" the python will pick this up as "10 Gauge"

I've others where I've said

```
gun_calibre = gun_calibre.replace(gun_calibre,".308")
if ".30" in gun_calibre:
gun_calibre = gun_calibre.replace(gun_calibre,".30")
```

Where because there is `.30` in both if statements the `.308` it will be grabbed as `.30` and not the `.308`.

---

- What would be causing this?
- My assumption was if it only meets the exact criteria in the " " then it would perform the command. Why is one overruling the other?

Comment: `my_str = my_str.replace(my_str, other_str)` is a very roundabout way of saying `my_str = other_str`.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do 2 things. First is use `elif` as @Oliver.R mentioned, but the second is you must order you comparisons starting with the most stringent.

For example, if you wanted to match `410 Gauge`, `10 Gauge`, and `0 Gauge`, you'll need to do the comparisons in the order the order I mentioned them.

```
if "410 Gauge" in gun_calibre:
    gun_calibre = gun_calibre.replace(gun_calibre,"410 Gauge")
elif "10 Gauge" in gun_calibre:
    gun_calibre = gun_calibre.replace(gun_calibre,"10 Gauge")
elif "0 Gauge" in gun_calibre:
    gun_calibre = gun_calibre.replace(gun_calibre,"0 Gauge")
```

However, since we are programming, let's do some programming to make this simpler and scalable. We can notice that the larger strings must be checked before the smaller strings so we can do somethings like this:

```
calibres = ['410 Gauge', '0 Gauge', '10 Gauge', '.30', '.308', '.22 LR', '.223']
sorted_calibres = sorted(calibres , key=len, reverse=True)

gun_calibre = ''
for calibre in sorted_calibres:
    if calibre in gun_calibre:
        gun_calibre = calibre
        break
```

Comment: The further extension of this then to be to use [RegEx](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to more generally capture things, such as `r"(\.\d+)|(\d+ Gauge)"` (https://regex101.com/r/6G22Yk/1)

Comment: @noslenkwah this seems to work, - its made the code a lot tidier than what i had so thanks for that.  However im still getting the same result of "10 Gauge" being printed when the string has "410 gauge" etc.  Any further ideas?  I've been playing with RegEx but i cant seem to get it to work.  keep getting errors about unhashable due to it being a list etc?

Comment: Do you have a minimal code sample and dataset to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 1):

It is finding and replacing the first gun calibre, however then when it searches the string again, it is finding the next substring (`"10 Gauge"` is in `"410 Gauge"`) - you could solve this the easiest way using `elif`:

```py
if "410 Gauge" in gun_calibre:
    gun_calibre = gun_calibre.replace(gun_calibre,"410 Gauge")
elif "10 Gauge" in gun_calibre:
    gun_calibre = gun_calibre.replace(gun_calibre,"10 Gauge")
```

Comment: And to answer your query relating to `'` and `"`, they are functionally equivalent, only difference being which characters can be used in the string (can use the other one inside your string without escaping it).

Comment: I updated using noslenkwah's loop and list of calibre options however i'm still getting the same issue of 410 gauge printing 10 gauge.  surely there is a search function to only print the exact match?